# Receive a notification when database has changed c#

Tags: c#, database, listener, mvvmcross

I currently loaded data when an application starts from a database through rest client get methods. I wanted to know how I will be able to track when the user changes the database and act on those changes?

This method populates data I need for my application start from a database. It is located in my viewmodel:

```
public async Task InitializeData()
```

Now I want to I guess do the same method when there is a change on the db? but how? T

Comment: This sounds like a job for Node. .Net works too though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the EntityFramework you could use the Database Command Logging.

Below is the code example from 
[www.entityframeworktutorial.net - Database Command Logging](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-logging.aspx)

```
public class Logger
{
    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EF Message: {0} ", message);
    }
}

class EF6Demo
{

    public static void DBCommandLogging()
    {
        using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
        {

            context.Database.Log =  Logger.Log;                
            var student = context.Students
                            .Where(s => s.StudentName == "Student1").FirstOrDefault<Student>();

            student.StudentName = "Edited Name";
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Logger class you could react with your code when the Log function will be called.